# jquery ajax call successfully running but page not updating

Tags: php, jquery

my jquery ajax call is updating my database but its not updating the page. I m not clear about the success parameter please help

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function changeStatus(userStatus,userId) {
      var getParameters = "userStatus = " + userStatus + "&userId = " + userId;
      $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: 'blogUsers.php',
         data: getParameters,
         success: function() {
         }
      });
   }
</script>
```

php:

```
<?php
   if( isset( $_GET['userId'] ) && isset( $_GET['userStatus'] ) ) {
      $userId = $_GET['userId'];
      $userStatus = $_GET['userStatus'];
      switch( $userStatus ) {
         case "1":
            $changeStatus=0;
            break;
         case "0":
            $changeStatus=1;
            break;
        default:
            $changeStatus="";
   }
   $Query = "UPDATE blog_users SET blog_user_status='$changeStatus' WHERE blog_user_id='$userId'";
   $Result = mysql_query( $Query );
}
?>
```

this is how the user grid is showing on page:

```
function viewUsers() {
$Query="SELECT * FROM blog_users";
$Result=mysql_query($Query);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($Result)) {
    $userId=$row['blog_user_id'];
    $userName=$row['blog_user_name'];
    $userEmail=$row['blog_user_email'];
    $userStatus=$row['blog_user_status'];
?>
<tr><td><?php echo $userId; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $userName; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $userEmail; ?></td>
<td><?php if($userStatus==1){echo "Active";}else echo "Banned"; ?></td>
<?php
$action="";
switch($userStatus){
    case "1":
        $action="Ban User";

        break;
    case "0":
        $action="Activate User";
        break;
    default:
        $action="";
}
?>
<td><a href="#" onclick="changeStatus(<?php echo $userStatus; ?>,<?php echo $userId; ?>);"><?php echo $action; ?></a></td>
<?php } } ?>
```

this is how i call function"

```
<td><a href="#" onclick="changeStatus(<?php echo $userStatus; ?>,<?php echo $userId; ?>);"><?php echo $action; ?></a></td>
```

and thsi is the part that needs to be updated:

```
<table class="tablesorter" cellspacing="0"> 
    <thead> 
        <tr> 
        <th class="header">userId</th> 
        <th class="header">userName</th> 
        <th class="header">userEmail</th>
        <th class="header">userStatus</th>
        <th class="header">Actions</th>                     
        </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
        <?php viewUsers(); ?>
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

In actual the `$action` variable should be changed to Activate user or Bann user on click !

Comment: Success in jquery.ajax is a function that is executed one the ajax query is resolved with a success (hence, no error occurred). This is the point where you place the code that changes the page. Your success-function is empty, therefore, nothing will change.

Comment: yeah i tried placing
success:function(data){
$(".tablesorter").html(data);
}
but it just placed the whole page again in my div

Comment: Hopefully no hacker can do `?userStatus=0&userId=1' OR '1'='1`

Comment: Lol, i m just learning these days not making any live projects so at this time i don't bother about hacking

Comment: Maybe try logging `data` to the console and look what the server actually returns. Then you can work from there as you narrowed down the source of your error.

Comment: what is the standard way of upating a part of page on success?

Answer (score 2):

You've got to remember that jQuery and PHP are completely independent of one another, and simply updating data in the database will not update the data on your page until you refresh, as the PHP code will only run when the page first loads, and not after. What you need to do is use your `success` method in the jQuery ajax call. Change your ajax call to

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'blogUsers.php',
    data:getParameters,
    success:function(data, status, jqxhr) {
      ... set users in view here ...
    }
  });
}
```

What format are you returning the data in from the server here? Is the `blogUsers.php` returning HTML, or is it returning a JSON array of users? If html, you can simply set the body of your response function to

```
$(".tablesorter tbody").html(data)
```

But I assume you're most likely returning JSON?

If you are, then you'll need to generate the HTML from within the success method. Something like this should work :

```
$(".tablesorter tbody tr").remove();
$.each(data, function(user){
  $(".tablesorter tbody").append(
      $("<tr></tr>").append(
          $("<td></td>").append(
              $("<a></a>", {
                  href: "#",
                  onclick: "changeStatus(" + user.userStatus ", " + user.userId + ")",
                  text: user.action
              })
          )
      )
  )
})
```

This snippet assumes your user objects have the properties name, userId, userStatus, and action, and that the users response is simply an array of user objects.

Obviously you'll want to build up the html in the format you want, this will just generate

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="#" onclick="updateStatus(status, id);">Action here</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

But it gives you a rough idea of how it'll work

Comment: Kindly see my udpated code.. I;ve pasted the viewUsers function that is calling on my page to show the grid

Comment: actually bloguser.php has a file included myfunctions.php.. so all the php code is coming for functions page.. bloguser has only markup and my ajax call

Comment: Ah ok. What you really need then is a different php file which just retrieves the users from the database and returns nothing but data. So something like blogUserJson.php (although I'd pick a better name) and in there, do your database query for the users, put each user in an array, and serialize it to JSON and return that.

Comment: Sir, I just started this jquery and php and the thing you are telling is going above my head :\ isn't there an easy way just to update the <td>$action</td> ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. PHP and jQuery are separate. Your variables such as $action are only there for PHP. jQuery doesn't know what they are, and doesn't know anything about them, as PHP runs on the server when the page loads, and jQuery runs on the client computer after the page has loaded. The only way to update your page is to make javascript change it I'm afraid.

Comment: Yeah you could do that, but you're still going to have to do it in javascript. There is no way for javascript and PHP to interact with each other.

Comment: when i tried putting 
$(".tablesorter").html(data);

in my success function... its showing the udpated results but its showing so many tables on my page :S i dont knwo from where they are coming

Comment: Well what html does it return? I assume your html return includes the table itself as well. Doing $(".tablesorter").html(data) is going to produce `<table><table>...</table></table>`, so if it does include the table itself, then do `$(".tablesorter").replaceWith(data) and it should then work.

Answer (score 0):

You had almost done all the code. What I am sure is that the php code which is your code to show the updated data was executed before the table has been updated through onclick event.

Try reloading the page like:

```
success:function() { //you will not have to pass any parameter 
                     on the function because you all done the show data in your `viewUsers()`.
  //your page here, e.g window.location.href: 'bla2.php';     
}
```